# Force Focus on AutoCompleteBox from Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, autocompletebox

It's not possible to do a `autocompletebox.Focus()`, but there seems to be a work around : `TextBox textBox = autoBox.Template.FindName("Text", autoBox) as TextBox;`

However, there is no method `FindName` in Windows Phone. How can I work around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the short chunk of source code from this blog about [VisualTreeEnumeration](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/Default.aspx).  (Note the comment about Toolkit's own VisualTreeExtensions class doesn't apply the the WP7 toolkit).

Now you can retrieve the internal TextBox with:-

```
textBox = autoBox.Descendents().OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Text");
```